# How to edit a text file in C created with a system command?

Tags: c, file-handling

I have written a program to print the output of the "Traceroute" command that run on the linux terminal. Here the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "SourceIP.c"
#include "RandomTraceroute.c"
#include "Time.c"

int main()
{
    unsigned char sourceIP[15];
    source(sourceIP);   
    printf("%s\n",sourceIP);

    unsigned char destIP[15];
    randIP(destIP); 
    printf("%s\n",destIP);

    char buff[100];
    timestamp(buff);
    printf ("%s\n", buff);

    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf),"traceroute -q 1 %s >output.txt",destIP);
    system(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

The task is to print this first three printf lines as the first three lines of the output.txt file by removing the existing first line of the text file. Can anyone suggest an answer for this. 
(Please consider about the time complexity of the code also)

Comment: `#include "SourceIP.c"
#include "RandomTraceroute.c"
#include "Time.c"`...hmmm.. in need of a good C book,

Comment: Maybe you want `popen()`?

Comment: In need of a mystic as well.

Comment: Those 3 c files are simply return 3 char arrays. The problem is printing those 3 values in the text file.

Comment: What @SouravGhosh is trying to say is, almost never include *.c files.  Compile them separately and link to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you think about following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

#include "SourceIP.c"
#include "RandomTraceroute.c"
#include "Time.c"

int main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    unsigned char sourceIP[15];
    source(sourceIP);   
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", sourceIP);

    unsigned char destIP[15];
    randIP(destIP); 
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", destIP);

    char buff[100];
    timestamp(buff);
    fprintf(f, "%s\n", buff);

    fclose(f);

    char buf[BUFSIZ];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf),"traceroute -q 1 %s 2> /dev/null >> output.txt", destIP);
    system(buf);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanx. It's working. But I couldn't get how the 1st line is removing. This code prints a phase from the existing first line of the traceroute output